# git on linux, Right path, wrong version number

Tags: linux, git, centos

```
[wen@localhost git-master]$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 1.9.0.GIT
[wen@localhost git-master]$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
[wen@localhost git-master]$ git --version
git version 1.7.1
```

Installed follow [Getting-Started-Installing-Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)

My linux dist info.

```
[wen@localhost git-master]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 19:59:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[wen@localhost git-master]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

What's wrong with this ?
BTW, I installed the `Development Tools` which contains `Git 1.7.1`.

Comment: Probably hashed path in your current shell session but, as you discovered, removing the system git will prevent that sort of problem from happening.

Comment: Yes, `type git` output is `hashed(xxx)`, but I don't get it.

Comment: Your shell remembers where it found the binary and doesn't search again. `which` always searches.

Comment: So, actually, the problem is the hashed.Just reopen the terminal will resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below, I resolve the problem.

```
yum remove git
exit
# reopen an terminal
```

Now, everything is ok :-)

**EDIT**

Actually, the problem is caused by hash(`man hash`,`help hash`),
you can clear *all cache* by `hash -r`, or *only one cache* `hash -d git`.

But, I think, remove the old version is not bad,saved my disk prevent the conflict.